# CruiseControl.NET Build Label Problem

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I'm labeling my assemblies using the CCNETLABEL environment variable and the SVN Revision number.  The problem I am facing is as follows:

Assume ProjectA is dependent on ProjectB

ProjectA is at build number X and ProjectB is at build number Y

When ProjectA is triggered, ProjectB is built as well.

Because CCNETLABEL = X+1 my version labeling was resulting as follows:

ProjectA build number = X+1 AND ProjectB build number = X+1 instead of the expected Y.

This is leading to versioning problems because the assemblies are being seen as a "newer" version.

**My question is:**

**I don't want to label each assembly built because of a change to a particular project with that project's CCNETLABEL.  Ideally I'd only want ProjectA to build assuming ProjectB has already been built thus saving the processing time of having to build ProjectB.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the  element of the ccnet.config file for each project, I was using "Rebuild" which forces all related projects to rebuild.  By changing this to "Build" it only builds dependent projects if there is a change that requires compilation.  Because CCNET retrieves the latest version always this is never an issue.  Problem solved.